# Animating transitions in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

I need to animate the div that contains all the app content when switching state, the problem is that when trying to animate both the leaving and entering div, they stack under each other until animation ends.

The solution I found on the internet is to place the div as `position:absolute` so they will be at exact same position, but this is weird when using the *angular-material* flex layout.

[I made a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ff2plEUAnLSLUESKjfA5?p=preview) with the *successful* way of achieving my animation, the problem stands in the css :

```
.placeholder {
  width: 450px;
  position: relative;
}
```

for the `position:absolute` to not break out my layout, I have to define a width on my container (`max-width` is not working) which I don't want, as my container size will be dynamic, is there a way of achieving this in another way ?

Also, if someone knows a good tutorial for learning angularjs transitions I'd be grateful :)

**Edit:** Can someone also explain me how to animate like this gif shows ? I've read that all ng-enter/ng-leave apply only to `ng-show`, and not to elements that are attached to DOM from the start:

[image]

Comment: You can achieve above animation in angular. You need to write you classes is css and will need few image. Read more about Angular Animation on
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate And 

http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/spinning-keyframes-animation